# SwiftUI: How to dismiss (not modaly) subview on button click?

Tags: swiftui

I have a messageView that is shown on the main view (not modaly - as subview of the main view) with VStack, that needs to be closed on button click. I found how to present and dismiss views modaly with SwiftUI, but did not found anythin specific for this case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you can provide sample code to demonstrate what you are attempting.

Correct me if I am wrong but my understanding from the question is that you would like to hide a view once a user taps on a button.

To do that you can use the @State property wrapper

```
struct MainView: View {
   @State private var isMessageViewHidden: Bool = false

   var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isMessageViewHidden = true
        }) {
            Text("itle")
        }
        if !isMessageViewHidden {
            MessageView()
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I manage to fix the problem just like this, with state for showing and hiding the subview. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it @Jay !